# AppleScript to copy images that names are multiple of 30 to another folder

Tags: applescript, macos

I have a folder with hundreds of pictures like this:
Montana_1.jpg, Montana_2.jpg, …, Montana_4500.jpg

I only want to use the pictures where the name is multiple of 30. I was wondering if an AppleScript would

1. Open the folder containing the pictures.
2. Copy only the pictures that are multiple of 30 like
   Montana_30.jpg, Montana_60.jpg, …, Montana_120.jpg.
3. Move to another folder.

Another way could be to delete any picture that is not multiple of 30.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from the command line. The following will match all images which are a multiple of 30 and copy them to the destination folder.

```
/bin/zsh -c "cp /path/to/source/Montana_{30..4500..30}.jpg /path/to/destination/"
```

- Replace `/path/to/source` with the path to the containing folder for the images.
- Replace `4500` with the number of the last image in the folder.
- Replace `/path/to/destination` with the path to the containing folder where the images which are a multiple of 30 will be copied to.

To move instead of copy, replace `cp` with `mv`.
To use this in an AppleScript, you can ‘do shell script’.